# Appropriateness of a "Best April Fools Day IT pranks" question

Tags: discussion

April Fools' day is coming up soon and it's been a few years since I've pulled any pranks off at my company. I'd like to get some ideas from the general populous, but I have a feeling it would get closed pretty quick. So I figured I'd ask here first. While we can twist the FAQ wording around to make it on topic, it's definitely not a productive question. What do the meta spirits think?

Comment: You should probably just ask this in the chat.

Comment: http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/b278/

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/comments/gfy1l/my_version_of_the_voice_activated_printer_april/

Comment: In the company I work atm, they pulled a nice one 2y ago: They sent out a mail telling about a spray that protects you from the dangers of WiFi-signals. You can use the spray to pretect your bedroom, the children's room, ... They also added a nicely photoshopped folder/flyer :)

Comment: Thank you @GroundZero that's awesome. Definitely going on our to-do list for this year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this would probably fall into the same vein as [the "Server Names" question](https://serverfault.com/questions/3668/what-are-the-most-manageable-and-interesting-server-naming-schemes-being-used) - "bad subjective" because there's no real way to decide what's the "best" prank ever pulled - it would wind up being a list-of-things rather than something of constructive use (though I suppose you could argue that coming up with a creative new way to scare the pants off your employees has some constructive merit it would be a little hard to say it's "professional" :-)

---

Of course nothing stops you from [hopping into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) to talk about pranks - you've got 10 days left to plan!

Comment: K, Makes sense. I figured as much considering a search for April Fools brought up no relevant results. I can't be the first one to have considered asking.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the sort of thing I'd love to read on some forum such as Spcierowks or Rettid.

As a professional Q&A site, this sort of question is completely into the opinionated, would lead to extended discussions, and is strongly discouraged these days. (Note that you can still find a few similar ancient examples in SF's early history, though most all of them should be closed by now.)

Answer (score 2):

ServerFault is meant to be Q&A about problems and solutions to those problems, not for opinions.

In the strict interpretation of what's on-topic, I'd say this is firmly on the "opinion-based" side of things. After all, it's impossible to have an actual "answer" to this question since there are no right or wrong answers and everything would be based on a subjective basis rather than being backed up by facts.

So, to answer your question: No, I do not believe even a well-written question about this topic would be appropriate here.